# Sml program -> confusion on "AS syntax error"

Tags: syntax, parameters, sml, poly

so I have to write a small program in SML ->>

> a file named ‘p0.sml’ that contains a function named `epoly`, which accepts as parameters a `list` of `real` values `a0` through `an`, and a single real value `x`. The list contains the coefficients of a polynomial of the form `a0 + a1x + a2x 2 + … + anx n`, where the real `x` used is the `x` parameter passed to your function. Your implementation must accept the list of coefficients as the first parameter and the value of `x` as the second. Your function must return the value of the polynomial specified by the parameters passed to it.

this is what I have so far but it won't compile because of a syntax error with as. "Error: syntax error found at AS". If you have any pointers that would be greatly appreciated.

```
fun epoly([], x:real) = 0.0
= epoly(L:real list as h::T, x:real) = h + (x * epoly(T, x));
```

Comment: Note that the "as pattern" serves no purpose here, since you never use `L`.

Comment: Additionally, there is no need to specify the types explicitly. Your SML compiler will correctly infer the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo. Your second `=` should be a `|`.

```
fun epoly([], x:real) = 0.0
  | epoly(L:real list as h::T, x:real) = 
      h + (x * epoly(T, x));
```

There is, further, no need to specify types. Your SML compiler can infer the types from data presented. Along with removing unnecessary bindings, this can be reduced to:

```
fun epoly([], _) = 0.0
  | epoly(h::T, x) = 
      h + (x * epoly(T, x));
```

From `fun epoly([], _) = 0.0` we know `epoly` will take a tuple of a list and some type and return `real`.

From:

```
  | epoly(h::T, x) = 
      h + (x * epoly(T, x));
```

We know that `x` is being multiplied by a `real`, so `x` must be `real`. And since `h` is being added to a `real`, it must be a `real`, so the entire list is a `real list`.

Thus the type of `epoly` can be inferred correctly to be `real list * real -> real`.

Comment: Re: "no need to specify types": This is certainly true, but it might not be a bad idea for newcomers to Standard ML to put in a few type annotations reflecting their expectations so that they get useful error-messages when their expectations turn out to be, for whatever reason, wrong.

Comment: That's fair. Though I think it's critical for newcomers to realize how type inference works. Otherwise they're missing one of the big draws of ML.